# Datagridview cell forecolor question (winform)

Tags: winforms, colors, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a requirement to display a text in various colors within a datagridview cell.

**I mean, within one same cell, I need to use several colors !**

Which color is to be applied depends on the value of each character.

Any clue? Is there any other object than the datagridview (like a sort of table for instance)

If I could use several Labels within the cell, it would do the job, but how?

Comment: Label controls only show text in a single color. That you can change the color *at all*, disrespecting the user's chosen color scheme, is a concession to bad design. I suggest not making the problem worse. This is difficult to implement anyway; you'll have to custom draw all of the text yourself. Next, you'll complain that your application is slow; this doesn't come free.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should derive your own label class from label and handle the drawing yourself.

Another approach would be handling the datagridview data binding event and creating as many labels as you need for your cell.

I would go with deriving in this case, since the implementation would consist mostly of pretty basic GDI+ stuff and is more flexible than always creating multiple labels.